# How to fill rest of the day with temperature_min and temperature_max of that day using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has 4 columns: **day**, **time**, **tmin** and **tmax**. tmin shows the **temperature_min** of the day and tmax shows the **temperature_max**.
What I want is to be able to fill all of the NaN values of one day with tmin and tmax of that day. For example I want to convert this dataframe:

```
   day time     tmin tmax 
0   01 00:00:00 NaN NaN
1   01 03:00:00 -6.8 NaN
2   01 06:00:00 NaN NaN
3   01 09:00:00 NaN NaN
4   01 12:00:00 NaN NaN
5   01 15:00:00 NaN 1.2
6   01 18:00:00 NaN NaN
7   01 21:00:00 NaN NaN
8   02 00:00:00 NaN NaN
9   02 03:00:00 -7.2 NaN
10  02 06:00:00 NaN NaN
11  02 09:00:00 NaN NaN
12  02 12:00:00 NaN NaN
13  02 15:00:00 NaN 1.8
14  02 18:00:00 NaN NaN
15  02 21:00:00 NaN NaN
```

to this dataframe:

```
       day time     tmin tmax
    0   01 00:00:00 -6.8 1.2
    1   01 03:00:00 -6.8 1.2
    2   01 06:00:00 -6.8 1.2
    3   01 09:00:00 -6.8 1.2
    4   01 12:00:00 -6.8 1.2
    5   01 15:00:00 -6.8 1.2
    6   01 18:00:00 -6.8 1.2
    7   01 21:00:00 -6.8 1.2
    8   02 00:00:00 -7.2 1.8
    9   02 03:00:00 -7.2 1.8
    10  02 06:00:00 -7.2 1.8
    11  02 09:00:00 -7.2 1.8
    12  02 12:00:00 -7.2 1.8
    13  02 15:00:00 -7.2 1.8
    14  02 18:00:00 -7.2 1.8
    15  02 21:00:00 -7.2 1.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `groupby` and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df.assign(**df.groupby('day')[['tmin', 'tmax']].transform('first'))
```

```
    day      time  tmin  tmax
0     1  00:00:00  -6.8   1.2
1     1  03:00:00  -6.8   1.2
2     1  06:00:00  -6.8   1.2
3     1  09:00:00  -6.8   1.2
4     1  12:00:00  -6.8   1.2
5     1  15:00:00  -6.8   1.2
6     1  18:00:00  -6.8   1.2
7     1  21:00:00  -6.8   1.2
8     2  00:00:00  -7.2   1.8
9     2  03:00:00  -7.2   1.8
10    2  06:00:00  -7.2   1.8
11    2  09:00:00  -7.2   1.8
12    2  12:00:00  -7.2   1.8
13    2  15:00:00  -7.2   1.8
14    2  18:00:00  -7.2   1.8
15    2  21:00:00  -7.2   1.8
```

Or, if you'd like to modify the original DataFrame instead of returning a copy:

```
df[['tmin', 'tmax']] = df.groupby('day')[['tmin', 'tmax']].transform('first')
```

Comment: Thank you user3483203 for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!

Comment: @user3483203 can I know what does `transform('first')` do here?

Comment: You can use a lot of operations with `transform`.  `transform` takes the result of `first()`, and propagates it to every row in the group.  If you just did `df.groupby('day').first()`, you would only have 2 rows.  If you mess around with the difference between `df.groupby('day').mean()` and `df.groupby('day').transform('mean')` (or almost any operation) you'll start to see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it not as neatly as @user3483203 has done!

```
import pandas as pd
myfile = pd.read_csv('temperature.txt', sep=' ')
mydata = pd.DataFrame(data = myfile)

for i in mydata['day']:
    row_start = (i-1) * 8 # assuming 8 data points per day
    row_end = (i) * 8
    mydata['tmin'][row_start:row_end] = pd.DataFrame.min(tempdata['tmin'][row_start:row_end], skipna=True)
    mydata['tmax'][row_start:row_end] = pd.DataFrame.max(tempdata['tmax'][row_start:row_end], skipna=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful and also 99% neat.

Answer (score 0):

just use the [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with the forward fill and back fill parameters:

```
df.tmin = df.groupby('day')['tmin'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
df.tmax = df.groupby('day')['tmax'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
```

Comment: I tried this but I want to exactly put **tmin** and **tmax** values of day 1 to **NaN** values of day 1 and also **tmin** and **tmax** of day 2 to **NaN** values of day 2. Your answer fill gaps with **tmax** and **tmin** and doesn't consider day values. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post any code, here's a general solution:

```
    Step 1: Create variables that will keep track of the min and max temps
    Step 2: Loop through each row in the frame
    Step 3: For each row, check if the min or max == "NaN"
    Step 4: If it is, replace with the value of the min or max variable we created earlier
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. So how can I somehow make it sensitive to day numbers? I mean Step 1 of the solution should take into account the day numbers, right? I don't really understand this part your solution.

Comment: For example ... create variable called "tmin" and set to 0  > loop through all values for a given day > if the temperature for given day is not NaN and lower than 0, set tmin to that > when you reach the end of a given day, tmin will contain the lowest temp

Comment: Suggesting iteration is rarely a good approach when using `pandas`